# How can I customise the Selenium IDE export?

Tags: selenium-ide

Within Selenium IDE for Firefox, under Options -> C# / NUnit / Webdriver, there is a button 'Source' to view the conversion formatter.

It is displayed in read-only format.

Is it possible to get access to this file in order to customise the export process?

Sorry if this seems like a trivial question, I've found plenty of people complaining about not being able to perform various tasks online and a few responses that indicate that custom export is supported, but I can't seem to find a way to access the file to perform the work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think I found a solution to this problem.

Though you can't customize any of the built in exports, like C# / NUnit / Webdriver, you can create a completely new exporter. I'd recommend modifying an excising one.

1. Get the source exporter you would like to modify. Ex Options->Options->Formats->C#/NUnit/Webdriver->Source. And copy it to a text editor.
2. Edit this code.
3. Options->Options->Formats->Add(button) and paste your new exporter.

I think you have to copy and paste the text, there is not file upload.

This worked for Selenium IDE 2.5.0

Hope this helps!

EDIT: In addition to my answer above, it may be easier to just write your own parser for the Source of your IDE Test.

Comment: This is old, but this is precisely what I needed. The exports does not support PyTest, which I was already using, so I'll attempt to make an exporter for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The source is read-only because it has been provided by a Selenium IDE Plugin. 
The source is usually helpful if you want to make a very simple formatter. Usually a better way is to create your own customised version of the formatter and package it in a plugin. Take a look at the source itself and the plugin tutorial at http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/plugins.jsp

You can find some more information and slides about Selenium IDE plugins on my blog.

Cheers,
Samit Badle

Selenium IDE Maintainer. Twitter: @samitbadle
Blog: http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/