# selenium IDE export as java/webdriver - override FirefoxDriver?

Tags: selenium-ide

Exporting as java/webdriver generates: driver = new FirefoxDriver(); Is there an option to override this to the browser of choice, or do you have to manually modify the code once it is generated?

Answer (score 2):

As it stands, there is no concrete option to override the browser that will be instanciated. However, you can accomplish what you want by adding a custom Java formatter that specifies the desired driver type. (since you can't directly modify the default Java formatters)

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24332377/3238902):

> 1. Get the source exporter you would like to modify:  Options > Options... > Formats > Java/JUnit4/WebDriver > Source. And copy it to a text editor.
> 2. Edit this code. (`driver = new FirefoxDriver()`)
> 3. Options > Options > Formats > Add(button) and paste your new exporter.

You might want to name it something like "Java  / Webdriver" or something, but basically then you can export tests that will run in the preferred browser